# How to add HTTP Verb HEAD to my application

Tags: restlet

I am new to Restlet Framework and developing the Restful APIs for my Service. We need to support HEAD http Verb in addition to GET, POST, DELETE. I am able to add support for the GET, POST, DELETE but not able to find how to add support for HEAD request. How can I add this support? Using the latest Restlet 2.x version.
I have read that, HEAD is routed using GET and in my testing, I see when I use HEAD it goes in to the GET method. How can I check if its GET or HEAD within that GET method so my requirements would be met?

If its HEAD, I only want to return headers and if its GET return headers and response body.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Thanks,
gvr

Comment: It's common for `HEAD` requests to just call the function for the `GET` request (so it knows the `Content-Length`), and just send back the headers, ignoring the body. Have you confirmed whether or not a `HEAD` request already does this?

Comment: Restlet engine calling GET for HEAD also, so my code is not getting the opportunity to find out if its HEAD or GET request. There is no HEAD annotation in Restlet. For both GET and HEAD Restlet calls method annotated for GET. So how can I find out if its a HEAD or GET from the method used for GET annotation? In case of HEAD I don't want to get the actual data but only meta info even from my backend system.

Comment: did you try something like `if(getMethod().equals(org.restlet.data.Method.HEAD)){/*HEAD implementation*/} else {/*GET implementation*/}` within the method annotated with `@Get`?

Comment: @Narsi It might help to include some of the code you're using at the moment.